# IBM plsql - cursor

Tags: sql, plsql, db2, cursor, plsqldeveloper

I am new with PLSQL (IDM db2) and I am trying to create a procedure to find and delete some admin_tasks if they exist.

Explanation:
By running the bellow query1, I can find out the list of tasks in the scheduler:

```
SELECT * FROM SYSTOOLS.ADMIN_TASK_LIST;
```

To delete the task, I can run this query2:

```
call sysproc.admin_task_remove('TASK_NAME', null);
```

So I want to create a procedure to delete all tasks with the pattern "My_Task_*".
This should delete all the tasks with that pattern and leave the other existent tasks intact. The procedure should handle cases where the admin_tasks doesn't exist, or no admin_tasks were ever created, and should run without throwing any errors.

I have researched and found out that this can be made using cursors.

Can you help me to implement this?

EDIT:
I managed to find this solution:

```
BEGIN
  FOR v1 AS c1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT NAME 
    FROM SYSTOOLS.ADMIN_TASK_LIST
    WHERE NAME LIKE 'My\_task\_%' ESCAPE '\'
   DO
    call sysproc.admin_task_remove(NAME, null);
  END FOR;
END
```

This seems to work except if the SYSTOOLS.ADMIN_TASK_LIST was not yet defined.

If it's not defined than I get this error when I run the query: If it is not defined I get this error
: [Code: -204, SQL State: 42704]

> "SYSTOOLS.ADMIN_TASK_LIST" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204,
> SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.25.1301

So how can I bypass this error? DOing something like first checking if SYSTOOLS.ADMIN_TASK_LIST is defined, if its defined to the above query if not do nothing.

Comment: I don't think [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer) works with IBM PL/SQL so it's not helpful to tag it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that your client tool uses '@' as a statement delimiter.

```
BEGIN
  FOR L1 AS 
    SELECT NAME 
    FROM SYSTOOLS.ADMIN_TASK_LIST
    WHERE NAME LIKE 'My\_task\_%' ESCAPE '\'
  DO
    CALL ADMIN_TASK_REMOVE (L1.NAME, NULL);
  END FOR;
END
```

**Update:**
With error handling for non-existing table. The error handler just "eats" the error on non-existing table use.
You must use dynamic sql for that.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR (5);
  DECLARE L_NAME VARCHAR (128);
  DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1; 
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42704' BEGIN END;
  PREPARE S1 FROM 
    '
    SELECT NAME 
    FROM SYSTOOLS.ADMIN_TASK_LIST
    WHERE NAME LIKE ''My\_task\_%'' ESCAPE ''\''
    ';
  OPEN C1;
  L1:
  LOOP
    FETCH C1 INTO L_NAME;
    IF SQLSTATE = '02000' THEN LEAVE L1; END IF;
    CALL ADMIN_TASK_REMOVE (L_NAME, NULL);
  END LOOP L1;
  CLOSE C1;
END
```

Comment: It's throwing this error:[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "MOVE (L1.NAME, NULL)".  Expected tokens may include:  "<psm_semicolon>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.25.1301

Comment: As I said: you must set the statement termination character to '@' in your client tool. Which tool do you use?

Comment: I did it. Check my answer bellow

Comment: By the way why are we using the 'My\_Task\_%' ESCAPE '\' since we could use 'My_Task_%' ?

Comment: Unescaped `_` character has special meaning for the `LIKE` predicate. It means "whatever single character". Look at the [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/1IDiAVGL).

Comment: ok, I edit my initial question. This works when the SYSTOOLS:ADMIN_TASK_LIST exists or is defined. But If it is not defined I get this error: [Code: -204, SQL State: 42704]  "SYSTOOLS.ADMIN_TASK_LIST" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.25.1301. Anyway to bypass this? Check my original post please

Comment: Look at the updated answer.

Comment: Is this correct: WHERE NAME LIKE ''My\_task\_%'' ESCAPE ''\'' or should it be  WHERE NAME LIKE 'My\_task\_%' ESCAPE '\' ?

Comment: Yes, my code is correct. Look at the [emulation](https://dbfiddle.uk/k6koRgK0).

Comment: If the question is "Is it possible to implement the solution without dynamic sql use", then the answer is: no. The statement using static request to a non-existing table even won't be compiled. Just in case: if a single quotation mark is used inside a string constant, it must be escaped by its doubling.